# Error when create thumb

Tags: php, thumbnails

I use this opensource 
http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

But i try create a thumb from my hosting get an error
This link image wish create a thumb.

```
http://pixhost.info/avaxhome/94/91/00179194.jpeg

error reading file http://pixhost.info/avaxhome/94/91/00179194.jpeg from remote host: Failed writing body (37 != 1448)
Query String : src=http://pixhost.info/avaxhome/94/91/00179194.jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have created manually two subfolders `cache` and `temp` in the directory where the timthumb.php is to be found. Those subfolders need to have the permissions set as open as possible (777 on a linux machine) in order to let the server user account write into these. Then everything should be fine. Please note that you cannot grab pictures from the web (as far as i know). Pictures should be placed on the local machine.

Example: `http://myserver.com/web/timthumb.php?src=scotland.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to come from a `curl` command :

```
$ch = curl_init ($src);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $src);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
if (curl_exec ($ch) === FALSE) {
    if (file_exists ($local_filepath)) {
        unlink ($local_filepath);
    }
    display_error ('error reading file ' . $src . ' from remote host: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close ($ch);
fclose ($fh);
```

It could come from the timeout. You may change it @ line 607

---

**EDIT :**

Alright, I tested it (since someone don't think pointing out the code doing the error and having guesses isn't enough) it works flawlessly on my server.

So it can be :

1. The timeout
2. The directory './cache' (that you can change in the class if needed @ line 17) not created/not with the good chmod so the `fopen` doesn't work. It is used to save the distant image on your server; if there's nowhere to save, then the `curl` command fails.

Comment: This should not be an answer unless its answers

Comment: 1- I consider it too long/unviewable if put in comment 2- I gave one solution (that I can't check right now, since I'm at work) that might work. 3- At least, I point out where the problem comes from, can help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because you ask curl to create a file name which your operating system (or perhaps more accurately your file system) doesn't allow it to use.

You code specifies that if the file does not exist, then proceed to fetch a copy from the url, and at no point are you creating a local file within your PHP Script.

Within your CURL Your code says

```
$fh = fopen ($local_filepath, 'w');
```

Within PHP **w** has a discription of:

Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, **attempt to create it**.

The main reason why files are unable to be created is the Folder Permissions, as we have a constant for that folder (`define ('DIRECTORY_CACHE', './cache');`) you need to have a folder called **cache** within the same directory of the executing script **./**

After This *CHMOD* The folders to **777** and run the script again

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you should add the domain, if it's external.

```
$allowedSites = array (
    'flickr.com',
    'picasa.com',
    'blogger.com',
    'wordpress.com',
    'img.youtube.com',
);
```

(See the timthumb.php file)